# Nested query in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get my `products` info from `AppServiceProvider`

## Logic

Category -> Subcategory -> Product

now I need to get `products` base on category `id`

**note:** you might think it's strange but it's not really, just imagine you want show products in category page from all subcategories of that category. Then you'll need such thing like i do. getting products base on `category_id` while you only save `subcategory_id` in products table.

this is my loop in `AppServiceProdiver`:

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
          $categories = Category::join('admin_designs', 'admin_designs.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')->get();
          foreach($categories as $category){
            $subcategory = Subcategory::join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')->first();
            $designs = Product::where('subcategory_id', $subcategory)->first();
          }
        $view->with('categories', $categories);
        });
```

result of that loop is:

```
{"id":2,"title":null,"slug":"laptop","image":"category-1516430091.jpg","imageAlt":null,"status_id":1,"meta_tags":"laptop,tags","meta_description":"laptop description","created_at":"2018-02-01 11:41:30","updated_at":"2018-02-01 11:41:30","category_id":1},
```

> PS: have no idea what is that! is not product/ is not complete
>   category `less title!`... :|

anyone can help with fixing that query?

Comment: Why dont u use eloquent query end relations?

Comment: What's the problem again ?

Comment: What is your  intention with the `$subcategory` and `$design` variables? You're overwriting them every time in the loop.

Comment: @AdamKozlowski whatever works i will take it, please share if you have better idea.

Comment: @MahdiYounesi read the question.

Comment: @btl to be honest? I try to get same `category_id` as is in `admin_designs` in `subcategory`. and try to get those subcategories in `designs` (products). obviously my function is broken. the logic is: get `category_id` in `admin_designs` -> get that `category_id` in `subcategories` -> get those `subcategories`(have same category_id in `products` and return them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
            $category = DB::table('admin_designs')
                              ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'admin_designs.category_id')
                              ->join('subcategories', 'subcategories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                              ->join('products', 'products.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
                                ->get();

            $view->with('category', $category);
        });
```

Hope it helps.